# 1:1 rendition of QR code as Bitmap, Android ZXing

Tags: android, bitmap, clone, qr-code, zxing

I've traversed the APIs of ZXing and had a good look around to see if I could find an example of somebody doing the same, but I have been unsuccessful thus far.

Let me explain the problem more clearly:

I can scan a QR code with ZXing et.al *and* save it as a bitmap/image **however** the image that is saved is ZXing's *interpretation of the data* encoded in the qr code.

What I need to do is to save the "pixels" of the QR code literally as a 2d array, with no processing / decoding occurring.

I need to store QR's which later need to be reproduced EXACTLY as the original, just storing a low-quality, not-very-well-aligned JPEG from the camera is insufficient.

When I'm scanning the QR code with ZXing and then re-generating it from the data from the scan programmatically, the resulting QR !== the original QR. I have tried all possible options for encoding, error correction etc, but can't get it!

Is there anything out there which will do this?

Thanks

J

Comment: Possibly related: [QR code generated by Android zxing library doesn't scan with most QR code scanners](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14837118/295004) but you are going to have to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60593416/edit) your question with more detail as to what you are saving and how you are recreating.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I've been awake for 48+ hours at this point, so will have to investigate further tomorrow to check if the proposed solution in the Possibly related gets things working for me and then update/remove question as appropriate.

Thanks for pointing this out :)